# A column named 'STATUS' already belongs to this DataTable

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable, datagridviewcolumn

in the sql query, it was fine.. and its running okay.. but once it go the process to.. the error come out "A column named 'STATUS' already belongs to this DataTable " 
here is the sql query

```
Dim sql As String = " SELECT DISTINCT LED.IDX As IDX, CORPCODE, UNITTYPECODE, UPPERFORMATIONCODE, FORMATIONCODE, LED.UNITCODE As UNITCODE,LED.STORECODE As STORECODE, LED.SECTIONNO As SECTIONNO, LED.PARTNO As PARTNO, "
            sql &= " LED.BATCHNO As BATCHNO, UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE, LEDGERDATE, ENTITLEMENT, HOLDING, SURPLUS, SHORTAGE, COSTHOLDING, COSTENTITLEMENT, INITIALSTOCK, EMPLOYQTY, FIGHTQTY, ITEMAGE1, ITEMAGE2, ITEMAGE3,"
            sql &= " ITEMAGE4, LED.BAH_BEREK, LED.JENIS_BEREK, JPTD_NO, LASTUPDATE, LED.ITEMTYPECODE As ITEMTYPECODE, LED.TOOLTYPECODE As TOOLTYPECODE, LED.PAKAIBHGCODE, LED.PAKAICODE, ITEMNIDX, LED.CREATEID As CREATEID, "
            sql &= " LED.UPDATEID As UPDATEID, LED.CREATEDATE As CREATEDATE, LED.UPDATEDATE As UPDATEDATE, "
            sql &= " USERID, RANKCODE, SERVICENO, USERNAME, DESIGNATIONCODE, PASSWORD, "
            sql &= " 'OPER' AS GROUPCODE,5 AS ACESSID, 0 AS STATUS "
            sql &= " FROM (LEDGER AS LED) "
            sql &= " LEFT JOIN NUSER   On NUSER.USERID = LED.UPDATEID   WHERE (1=1)   "
            If condation <> "" Then
                sql += condation
            End If
            sql &= " UNION SELECT DISTINCT LED.IDX As IDX, CORPCODE, UNITTYPECODE, UPPERFORMATIONCODE, FORMATIONCODE, LED.UNITCODE As UNITCODE, LED.STORECODE As STORECODE, LED.SECTIONNO As SECTIONNO, LED.PARTNO As PARTNO, "
            sql &= " LED.BATCHNO As BATCHNO, UNITITEMCATEGORYCODE, LEDGERDATE, ENTITLEMENT, HOLDING, SURPLUS, SHORTAGE, COSTHOLDING, COSTENTITLEMENT, INITIALSTOCK, EMPLOYQTY, FIGHTQTY, ITEMAGE1, ITEMAGE2, ITEMAGE3,"
            sql &= " ITEMAGE4, LED.BAH_BEREK, LED.JENIS_BEREK, JPTD_NO, LASTUPDATE, LED.ITEMTYPECODE As ITEMTYPECODE, LED.TOOLTYPECODE As TOOLTYPECODE, LED.PAKAIBHGCODE, LED.PAKAICODE, ITEMNIDX, LED.CREATEID As CREATEID, "
            sql &= " LED.UPDATEID As UPDATEID, LED.CREATEDATE As CREATEDATE, LED.UPDATEDATE As UPDATEDATE,"
            sql &= " '','','','','','','OPER',5 , STATUS "
            sql &= " FROM LEDGER_HISTORY LED WHERE (1=1) "
            If condation <> "" Then
                sql += condation
            End If
```

for the process.i dont know where need to fix.. can anyone help me to solve this proble. here is the process code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim cond As String = ""
    If cboFormasi.SelectedValue.ToString.Length > 0 Then
        cond &= " AND led.FORMATIONCODE=" & ParseStringToSQL(cboFormasi.SelectedValue)
    End If
    If cboUnit.SelectedValue.ToString.Length > 0 Then
        cond &= " AND led.UNITCODE=" & ParseStringToSQL(cboUnit.SelectedValue)
    End If

    Try
        dt = objLejer.ExporttAll(cond)
        If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            dt.Columns.Add("BATCHDATE")
            dt.Columns.Add("NSNNO")
            dt.Columns.Add("MFGNO")
            dt.Columns.Add("ITEMCATEGORYCODE")
            dt.Columns.Add("MATERIALTYPECODE")
            dt.Columns.Add("Image")
            dt.Columns.Add("SIAPSIAGA")
            dt.Columns.Add("MEASURECODE")
            dt.Columns.Add("ITEM_IMAGE")
            dt.Columns.Add("MIS_TAG")
            dt.Columns.Add("MIS_NAME")
            dt.Columns.Add("SFS_TAG")
            dt.Columns.Add("TSNSTSB")
            dt.Columns.Add("FLAG")
            dt.Columns.Add("COST")
            dt.Columns.Add("ITEMNAME")
            dt.Columns.Add("OLDPARTNO")
            dt.Columns.Add("ISDEL")
            dt.Columns.Add("STATUS")
            dt.AcceptChanges()
```

Hope someone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: ExportAll Function will go to the sql query above

Comment: Hmm… what part of _”A column named 'STATUS' already belongs to this DataTable”_ do you not understand? You may also want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You cannot have two columns with the same name.  STATUS in SQL select and STATUS added manually.